# Writing RegEx to locate a certain word in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following code

```
b.element(:id, "SearchFor").send_keys "843842983"
b.element(:xpath, "//input[@value='Search']").click
b.text_field(:id, "AmountPaid").set "343"
b.element(:id, "paytype0").click
b.element(:css, "label.radio-custom-label.ng-binding").click
b.element(:id, "xxx").send_keys "11"
```

I want to locate `b.element` if `.send_keys` has been followed

for an example,I want to locate `b.element` when the string is

```
b.element(:id, "xxx").send_keys "11"
```

not when

```
b.element(:id, "paytype0").click
```

I am able to locate the whole string `b.element().send_keys` by writing the following regular expression `b.element\(.*\).send_keys` but I could not locate `b.element`.

Can anyone help me how to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to do this [**`b\.element(?=\([^)]*\)\.send_keys)`**](http://rubular.com/r/MIAz5gEuaG)?

Comment: probably question needs some more clarification as to what is needed... the given regex needs improvement, but it will still match the two lines containing `send_keys`

Comment: You said, “I have the following code”. It’s not code. It’s just a string and where the string came from is irrelevant. Answers should work equally well if it’s your grocery list and the target substring is “lettuce”. Moreover your text is not a valid Ruby object. It needs to be surrounded be single quotes or be part of a heredoc. Also, it’s helpful to assign a variable to the string (`str = ‘b.element(:I’d,...send_keys, “11”’`) so that readers can refer to the variable in answers and comments without having to define it.

Comment: @Sundeep You are welcome to write your answer.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland I am using Ruby Mine editor which give me Search and replace option where I can write RegEx to match and replace . If you still want me to change the question I will do so!

Comment: I didn't ask you to edit your question. That's up to you. I just pointed out some problems with it.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Okay Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for asserting rather than matching. Asserting doesn't consume characters but matching does. For assertions you have to use lookarounds here:

```
b\.element(?=\([^)]*\)\.send_keys)
```

This is nearly your own solution but put in a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

[Live demo](http://rubular.com/r/MIAz5gEuaG)

*P.S. escape dots when they literally mean a dot character*